How can I get the British pound character '£' or the hash '#' key be registered by VNC server?
When I connect to a VNC screen both the pound £ and the hash # characters are not sent. They are both entered by the Shift 3 key.
I find that unusual because it is such a common key to press unless the VNC servers or clients handle it differently.
The server in question is /usr/bin/x0tigervncserver, and I believe it has some options to allow keys to be passed through or remap them and I wonder if that will fix the problem.
The manual for X0tigervnc has key related options below and I wonder if I can set them to fix the problem.

RemapKeys

RawKeyboard

AcceptKeyEvents


The OS is Linux on both ends.
I changed the server to x11vnc after which the keys work and noticed that it displays the message
added missing keysym to X display: 093 0xa3 "sterling"
at start up so I suspect X0tigervnc is not doing the same. x11vnc is rather slow though.
